# NODE JS - Puppeteer : Save data in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I discover NODE JS and I would like to recover data (Demandes and Offres) contained in my pageScraper.js file in JSON format in a new data.json file thanks to my code contained in pageController.js.
Here is the content of my file pageScraper :

```
     const scraperObject = {
    url: 'https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha',
    async scraper(browser){
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
        await page.goto(this.url);

        await page.waitForSelector('#onetrust-reject-all-handler');
        await page.click('#onetrust-reject-all-handler');
    
        const result = await page.evaluate(() => {

            let demandes = document.querySelector('#main-content > div > section:nth-child(3) > div.css-gg4vpm > div.css-0 > div.css-qt7qal > div.chakra-stack.css-1g42e87 > div > a.chakra-button.css-2zzyy5 > p').innerText;

            let offres = document.querySelector('#main-content > div > section:nth-child(3) > div.css-gg4vpm > div.css-0 > div.css-qt7qal > div.chakra-stack.css-1g42e87 > a > p').innerText;

            return {demandes, offres}
          })

          console.log(result);
          await browser
          browser.close()

    }
}

module.exports = scraperObject;
```

And now here is the content of my file pageController :

```
const pageScraper = require('./pageScraper');
const fs = require('fs');
async function scrapeAll(browserInstance){
    let browser;
    try{
        browser = await browserInstance;
        let scrapedData = 
        fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(scrapedData), 'utf8', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("The data has been scraped and saved successfully! View it at './data.json'");
        });
        console.log(scrapedData)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("Could not resolve the browser instance => ", err);
    }
}


module.exports = (browserInstance) => scrapeAll(browserInstance)
```

I don't know what to put in my scrapedData variable.

Comment: Why not call the `pageScraper.scraper` function, e.g. `const scrapedData = await pageScraper.scraper(browser)`? You went through a lot of trouble to write it, so you might as well use it. You also forgot to `return result` at the end of the `scraper` function. `fs.writeFile` doesn't return anything so there's no point in assigning it. It's incongruous that the `scrape` function closes the browser. Seems like the caller should do that (use a `.finally` block to ensure no memory leak on error).

Comment: Seems to be fixed as of [Node JS : Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73072402/node-js-error-evaluation-failed-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-r/73073487#73073487)