# Node JS : Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

My code was working and the error: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText') came back. I don't understand why. I try to get the text contained in the tags and send it in a JSON document
Here is my code:

```
const scraperObject = {
    url: 'https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha',
    async scraper(browser){
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
        await page.goto(this.url);

        await page.waitForSelector('#onetrust-reject-all-handler');
        await page.click('#onetrust-reject-all-handler');

        const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let demandes = document.querySelector('#main-content > div > section:nth-child(3) > div.css-gg4vpm > div.css-0 > div.css-qt7qal > div.chakra-stack.css-1g42e87 > div > a.chakra-button.css-2zzyy5 > p').innerText;
            let offres = document.querySelector('#main-content > div > section:nth-child(3) > div.css-gg4vpm > div.css-0 > div.css-qt7qal > div.chakra-stack.css-1g42e87 > a > p').innerText;
           
            return {demandes, offres}
          })
          console.log(result);
          browser.close()
          return result
    }
}

module.exports = scraperObject;
```

Here is what was displayed in my JSON file when the code was running:

{"demandes":"Acheter à 1 365 €","offres":"Vendre à 784 € ou demander plus"}

My JSON is controlled in this file "pageController" :

```
const pageScraper = require('./pageScraper');
const fs = require('fs');
async function scrapeAll(browserInstance){
    let browser;
    try{
        browser = await browserInstance;
        const scrapedData =  await pageScraper.scraper(browser)
        fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(scrapedData), 'utf8', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("The data has been scraped and saved successfully! View it at './data.json'");
        });
        console.log(scrapedData)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("Could not resolve the browser instance => ", err);
    }
}


module.exports = (browserInstance) => scrapeAll(browserInstance)
```

And I don't know how to modify it

Thanks in advance

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns `null` if it can find an element matching the selector. You might execute the script before the element you are looking for is parsed or added to the DOM by a script of the page.

Comment: It's a good idea to explain what you're trying to accomplish so I can be sure my answer actually does that. `await browser` doesn't do anything, `browser.close()` isn't awaited, long browser-generated selectors are often brittle, and you probably should wait for your selectors before trying to pull their text content. If they never show up, then there's more work to be done to investigate the page-specific reason why.

Comment: Simplest fix for the error itself is to write `?.innerText`.  Of course, you should have a contingency plan for what happens when the elements you are looking for are not found in the document.

Comment: Here is what was displayed in my JSON file when the code was running:

{"demandes":"Acheter à 1 365 €","offres":"Vendre à 784 € ou demander plus"}

Comment: @Wyck obviously OP wants the data, so simply not crashing doesn't help. The crash is good because it tells you the data that should be there isn't there, which is the entire point of the script. `?` just silences a useful error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of those massive browser-generated selectors. If just one class or element in the chain changes, the whole thing breaks.

Easier than messing with the DOM is intercepting the response that has the data JSON in it:

```js
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^15.4.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  const url = "https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha";
  const responseP = page.waitForResponse(async response => {
    if (response.url() === "https://stockx.com/api/p/e") {
      const payload = await response.json();
      return payload?.data?.product?.market?.bidAskData;
    }
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const result = await (await responseP).json();
  await fs.writeFile("result.json", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  console.log(result.data.product.market.bidAskData);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Output:

```json
{
  highestBid: 803, // vendre / offres
  highestBidSize: '43',
  lowestAsk: 1332, // acheter / demandes
  lowestAskSize: '42',
  __typename: 'BidAskData'
}
```

My numbers are bit different than yours since I'm in the USA.

This doesn't have the fancy text, but that probably saves a step for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, thats what I wanted but how do I know that I have to search in this path: payload?.data?.product?.market?.bidAskData; please ?
And in the instruction I received I have to save the information in another json file

Comment: To find the path, I looked at the JSON [in a tool](https://ggorlen.github.io/json-dive) and clicked on the data I wanted. If you want to write to a file, see [Write / add data in JSON file using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856232/write-add-data-in-json-file-using-node-js).

Comment: Thank you how can i use your tool please ?

Comment: Paste the JSON in and search for the path you want, then click on it. There are many other interactive JSON navigators out there as well. But I've already done the work to find the path so there's no more action needed here, unless you're curious or there's some other data you want. Does the answer resolve the issue for you?

Comment: Not really, because I want to get the highestBid and lowestAsk for each size store them in a new JSON file but with this new code I don't see how to do it (I am a beginner). I would like to understand a bit more how it works and how to do it again on my own.
Thanks in advance

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question. The data is all written to file here, so is the problem at this point difficulty in extracting information from JSON, or Puppeteer retrieving the wrong data? Can you edit your question to show the exact JSON you expect as output? Thanks.

Comment: I'm working with your code now but the JSON output doesn't come in a new file, I just want to add that please.

Comment: I added the JSON file write. Did you see the update? It's writing all of the data but it's easy enough to modify it to only write the single key for `result.data.product.market.bidAskData` if that's what you want.

Comment: I had not seen the update. Thank you and yes I want to modifiy the key please

Comment: OK, did you try `await fs.writeFile("result.json", JSON.stringify(result.data.product.market.bidAskData, null, 2));`? All you have to do is put the variable you want to write into the call. See [Write / add data in JSON file using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856232/write-add-data-in-json-file-using-node-js) for the canonical thread for this task.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you edit the post to show exactly the JSON you want, it's probably very simple for me to produce that result. But if you don't show me the JSON you want, I have to guess, which means we'll have to go back and forth for a long time to figure out what you want, if we ever manage to get there.

Comment: Yes but it didnt work because I created an other file which is name "pageController"

Comment: Again, I don't know what this means.

Comment: I added the pageController file into the issue

Comment: Okay, cool. So what is the problem? Put my code into this function if you want it in that function.

Comment: I would like to add your code in mine

Comment: Feel free to do so. Plop it into your function and you're done, right? What is the problem?

Comment: I just don't know how to proceed. I don't know what to change in pageController

Comment: So `return result.data.product.market.bidAskData` from `pageScraper.scraper` and write it to file? You don't have to change anything in `pageController` as far as I can tell. That said, I wouldn't use the callback `fs.writeFile` when you're already in `async` code. Use `fs.promises` as shown above--much cleaner.

Comment: Ok thank you but I have this error : Could not resolve the browser instance =>  TypeError: pageScraper.scraper is not a function

Comment: Can you show the exact code you're using now, including how you're calling the function? Please keep your original code, though, because that's the scraping task which is the meat of the question, and should be useful to future visitors. Wiring things together to fit your app-specific needs is usually left as an exercise because it's incidental to the scraping techniques you're primarily asking about. You might want to open another question, with that in mind.

Comment: there is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73083298/node-js-typeerror-pagescraper-scraper-is-not-a-function