# NODE JS : TypeError: pageScraper.scraper is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm a beginner in NodeJS.

I try to get the highestBid and the lowestAsk for each size (38,39,40,..) and store them in a new JSON file (data.json) but when I run it this error appears:
*TypeError: pageScraper.scraper is not a function*

Here is my code :

File brower.js :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function startBrowser(){
    let browser;
    try {
        console.log("Ouvrir le navigateur......");
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
            'ignoreHTTPSErrors': true
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Impossible de créer une instance de navigateur => : ", err);
    }
    return browser;
}

module.exports = {
    startBrowser
};
```

File index.js :

```
const browserObject = require('./browser');
const scraperController = require('./pageController');

//Start the browser and create a browser instance
let browserInstance = browserObject.startBrowser();

// Pass the browser instance to the scraper controller
scraperController(browserInstance)
```

File pageScraper.js :

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^15.4.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  const url = "https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha";
  const responseP = page.waitForResponse(async response => {
    if (response.url() === "https://stockx.com/api/p/e") {
      const payload = await response.json();
      return payload?.data?.product?.market?.bidAskData;
    }
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const result = await (await responseP).json();
  await fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  console.log(result.data.product.market.bidAskData);

})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

File pageController :

```
const pageScraper = require('./pageScraper');
const fs = require("fs").promises;
async function scrapeAll(browserInstance){
    let browser;
    try{
        browser = await browserInstance;
        const scrapedData =  await pageScraper.scraper(browser)
        fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(scrapedData), 'utf8', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("The data has been scraped and saved successfully! View it at './data.json'");
        });
        console.log(scrapedData)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("Could not resolve the browser instance => ", err);
    }
}


module.exports = (browserInstance) => scrapeAll(browserInstance)
```

What should I do. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no function `scraper` in `pageScraper.js` (or anywhere else ...) And there is also no export from `pageScraper.js` So you could start with defining a `scraper` function and export it ...

Comment: Thank you can you explain more please ?

Comment: Based on the [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73072402/node-js-error-evaluation-failed-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-r/73073487?noredirect=1#comment129076940_73073487), you didn't try to move the code I provided into your existing function, you just replaced the whole file, which won't work because you lost your export. I suggest reading that thread again. Beyond that, a lot of these functions seem like pointless abstractions and show confused responsibilities. Why do you _need_ this exact design and what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I took the code you made because it works exactly as I would have liked, what I had was not really what I expected. I was instructed to get the highestBid and the lowestAsk for each size (38,39,40,..) and store them in a new JSON file (data.json).
That's why I used your code because it returns exactly what I need.

Comment: Do you have any idea ?